Context Provider not passing value to children
I am trying to create a parent/overarching context. The purpose of the context is to store UserInfo which should then be available to all children.
UserInfo is set by getting config from an API.
Context.ts:
import type { User } from 'my-lib';
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

export const UserContextProps = {
    setUser?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<User>>,
    userConfig?: User
}

export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextProps>({});

UserProvider.tsx
import { UserContext } from './Context'

const UserProvider = ({children}) =>{
    const [data, setUser] = useState<User>({});
  
    useEffect(() =>{
        fetchData().then(res => setUser(res.data))
    },[]);       
   
   return(
       <UserContext.Provider value={{setUser: setUser, userConfig: data}}>
           {Object.keys(user).length > 0 ? (
               <>{children}</>
           ) : (
               <div>Loading</div>
           )}
       </UserContext.Provider>
   )
}

Our app is made up of many small sites like cart.html, description.html, profile.html each of these has its own component. I am trying to wrap each of these with UserProvider so the children:
1. Render after userConfig is set
2. Have access to userConfig

Cart.tsx
import { UserProvider } from 'UserProvider';
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from './Context'

export const UserCartApp = () => {

    const { userConfig } = useContext(UserContext);

    return (
        <UserProvider>
            <Header userConfig={userConfig} />
            <SelectedProducts userConfig={userConfig} />
            <SubTotal userConfig={userConfig} />
            <Footer />
        </UserProvider>
    )
}

Inside  i have:
Header.tsx
export const Header = ({userConfig}) => {
    
    console.log('header config', userConfig);
....
....

The above console.log of userConfig is always {}

Issue
Components not wrapped in the Context provider will receive the default value.
export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextProps>({});

The UserContext has a default value of {}.
Since UserCartApp is the component rendering the UserProvider component providing the UserContext it can't itself access the provided value.
export const UserCartApp = () => {
  const { userConfig } = useContext(UserContext); // <-- receives default {} value

  return (
    <UserProvider> // <-- Provides the context
      <Header userConfig={userConfig} />
      <SelectedProducts userConfig={userConfig} />
      <SubTotal userConfig={userConfig} />
      <Footer />
    </UserProvider>
  );
};

Solution
Lift the UserProvider component higher in the ReactTree such that it can provide the UserContext value to UserCartApp.
Example:
<UserProvider>
  <UserCartApp />
</UserProvider>

export const UserCartApp = () => {
  const { userConfig } = useContext(UserContext); // <-- receives { setUser: setUser, userConfig: data } value

  return (
    <>
      <Header userConfig={userConfig} />
      <SelectedProducts userConfig={userConfig} />
      <SubTotal userConfig={userConfig} />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

Improvement/Suggestion
One of the problems the React Context API solves for though is props drilling. It doesn't make sense to access the context value in the parent component and then pass it down as props to each child component. An improvement here would be to simply have each child use the const { userConfig } = useContext(UserContext);.
Example:
const Header = () => {
  const { userConfig } = useContext(UserContext);

  ...
};

const SelectedProducts = () => {
  const { userConfig } = useContext(UserContext);

  ...
};

const SubTotal = () => {
  const { userConfig } = useContext(UserContext);

  ...
};

export const UserCartApp = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <SelectedProducts />
      <SubTotal />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};


Thanks @Drew Reese. I like your Improvement/Suggestion. In the last snippet, where does the Provider sit?

@OamPsy The provider can be rendered anywhere higher in the ReactTree than the consumers. Leave it in UserCartApp or anywhere above it. Does this make sense?

Yup, thanks. Will give it a try.

Ah, so i think i see what the issue is, but not solution. Context.ts, Header.tsx and UserProvider.tsx are in a local lib, as they are shared. Cart.tsx is in my app. Context.ts, Header.tsx and UserProvider.tsx get bundled app and added to myApps package.json as 'dependencies': { 'my-lib': 'workspace:*'.....

So because in our lib, we create mini bundles ie a UserProvider.js and a Header.js.. looking at compiled code, they dont share the same instance of the context, hence why Header is always {}... Cart.tsx now get the user config

Confirmed, in UserCartApp and UserProvider share the same createContext()... Header has its own createContext()

You are using UserContext in UserCartApp which is not wrapped by UserProvider. Instead of that use it in Header like this.
export const Header = () => {
    const { userConfig } = useContext(UserContext);
    console.log('header config', userConfig);

